# Were there any cases where one tried to falsify evidence with DeepFake?

Tags: evidence

Were there any cases, anywhere in the world, where one tried to falsify **evidence** with *Deepfake*, which is a technology powered by AI to create fake facial videos?

Comment: I will point out that my answer took five seconds of Googling for the term, "falsified evidence deepfake". It does appear to be the most famous example, other results on the first page of results seem to focus on legislation brought in to counter this potential threat.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

> As a child custody battle unfolded behind the closed doors of a
> British courtroom, a woman said her husband was dangerous and that she
> had the recording to prove it.
>
> Except, it turned out she didn’t.
>
> The husband’s lawyer revealed that the woman, using widely available
> software and online tutorials, had doctored the audio to make it sound
> like his client, a Dubai resident, was making threats.
>
> Byron James, an attorney with the firm Expatriate Law in Dubai, told
> the United Arab Emirates newspaper the National in February 2020 that
> by studying the metadata on the recording, his experts revealed that
> the mother had manipulated it. Under U.K. law, custody proceedings are
> confidential, but the National reports it took place at some point in
> 2019.

https://www.abajournal.com/web/article/courts-and-lawyers-struggle-with-growing-prevalence-of-deepfakes

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. This seems to be a case of audio deepfakes used to fake evidence. Do you know any cases where video deepfakes are involved, too?

Comment: @КонстантинВан - I can't find any examples, however in many parts of the world evidence for civil cases, especially those involving children, isn't made public. There's a couple of academic papers outlining the potential threat and some articles about legislative bodies looking at how to deal with hypothetical situations of it happening.